# limit of $\cos^n(\frac{\pi}{n})$

Tags: limits

Pretty self explanatory - what is a nice way to show that
$(\cos(\frac{\pi}{n}))^n\to 1$ as $n\to\infty$, where $n$ are integers?

Comment: Maybe not a 'nice way', but L'hospital's rule would work here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $$\cos (x) = 1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}-... \tag{$x \to 0$}$$
we have
$$\cos \frac{\pi}{n} = 1 + O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right) \tag{$n\to \infty$}$$
which implies $$\cos^n\frac{\pi}{n} = \left(1 + O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right) \right)^n \to 1 \tag{$n\to\infty$}$$

Comment: thanks, my real analysis is a little rusty though - whats the reasoning for $\cos(\pi/n)=1+O(1/n^2)$ here? A geometric series bound on the tail?

Comment: "use big O notation for everything after the first term" is very far from rigorous analysis. A correct analysis would be to use one of the remainder theorems or a geometric series tail bound. The former says that $\cos(x)=1+a(x) \frac{x^2}{2}$ where $a(x)=\cos^{(2)}(z(x))=-\cos(z(x))$ and $z(x)$ is between $0$ and $x$, thus $a(x) \in [-1,1]$.

Comment: thanks @Ian, that clarifies it. Is there an easy rule of thumb for when we can assert something like $c_1/x+c_2/x^2+c_3/x^3+\ldots = O(1/x)$, or do we have to go about trying to construct a geometric series bound in each case.

Comment: @MerkZockerborg If it is in the form of the tail of a Taylor series, you can use a remainder theorem (even if you don't know that the Taylor series is convergent). Otherwise you usually need to do some kind of tail bound like that "by hand". Of course there are some of these geometric tail bounds that you can figure out in an abstract context, for example for Taylor series where $f^{(k)}(x)$ grows at most exponentially fast with $k$, where the base is uniform in $x$.

Comment: @Ian I kind of hand waved the "use big O notation" part, my bad. Something I should probably avoid in the future.

Comment: I just deleted a *taylor series* answer that I originally posted, because I hadn't scrutinized your answer closely enough - I didn't realize that your answer was saying the same thing.

Comment: all good. And for the last step of the argument above, are we using some fact like

$f(n)\to 0 \implies (1+O(f))^n\to 1$? Or is this not true in general, and instead we're using that for large $n$ we have a sandwich

$(1-C/n^2)^n\leq (1+O(1/n^2))^n\leq (1+C/n^2)^n$, where $C$ is a positive contant, and the lower and upper bounds both $\to 1$

Comment: upon further thought it does seem that $f(n)\to 0$ is insufficient to get $(1+O(f))^n\to 1$ in general.

Comment: @MerkZockerborg Your argument with sandwich looks fine. Also, intuition might come from 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1 + O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right) \right)^n = \lim_{n\to\infty}\color{blue}{\left(1 + O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right) \right)}^{\color{blue}{O(n^2)}\frac{n}{O(n^2)}} = e^{\lim_{n\to\infty}O(1/n)}=1$$

Answer (score 3):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\cos^n\left(\frac\pi n\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\exp\left(\ln\left(\cos^n\left(\frac\pi n\right)\right)\right)=\exp\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}n\ln\left(\cos\frac\pi n\right)\right)$$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}n\ln\left(\cos\frac\pi n\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln\left(\cos\frac\pi n\right)}{\frac1n}$$

Let $x=\frac1n$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln\left(\cos\frac\pi n\right)}{\frac1n}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\ln(\cos(\pi x))}x$$

Applying l'Hopital's rule,

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\ln(\cos(\pi x))}x=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\frac{-\pi\sin(\pi x)}{\cos(\pi x)}}1=\lim_{x\to0}-\pi\tan(\pi x)=-\pi\tan0=0$$

Thus,

$$\exp\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}n\ln\left(\cos\frac\pi n\right)\right)=\exp(0)=1$$

Answer (score 2):

We can get much more than the limit $$a_n=\cos^n\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)\implies \log(a_n)=n\log \left(\cos \left(\frac{\pi }{n}\right)\right)$$
$$\cos \left(\frac{\pi }{n}\right)=1-\frac{\pi ^2}{2 n^2}+\frac{\pi ^4}{24
   n^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^6}\right)$$
$$\log \left(\cos \left(\frac{\pi }{n}\right)\right)=-\frac{\pi ^2}{2 n^2}-\frac{\pi ^4}{12
   n^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^6}\right)$$
$$\log(a_n)=-\frac{\pi ^2}{2 n}-\frac{\pi ^4}{12
   n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^5}\right)$$
$$a_n=e^{\log(a_n)}=1-\frac{\pi ^2}{2 n}+\frac{\pi ^4}{8 n^2}-\frac{\pi ^4 \left(4+\pi ^2\right)}{48
   n^3}+\frac{\pi ^6 \left(16+\pi ^2\right)}{384
   n^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^5}\right)$$

Comment: @Angelo. Thanks for pointing the typo !

Comment: thanks. Am I correct in thinking that at each step, you're plugging the series expansion for the previous expression into the expansion for $log(-)$, $e^{(-)}$ etc?

Also, is there an intuitive explanation for why using $e^{\log(a_n)}$ gives a nice series expression for $a_n$, but trying to directly calculate the series expression from $a_n$ doesn't really work? And is this a common trick?

Comment: @MerkZockerborg. I gave you a simple step by step procedure.  It works also directly : look at  https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Series%5BCos%5BPi%2Fn%5D%5En%2C%7Bn%2CInfinity%2C4%7D%5D

Answer (score 0):

Let $L=\lim_{n\to+\propto}\begin{pmatrix}
cos\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\pi}{n}\\ 
\end{pmatrix}\\ 
\end{pmatrix}^n$. We obtain: $log(L)=\lim_{n\to+\propto}n\cdot log\begin{pmatrix}
cos\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\pi}{n}\\ 
\end{pmatrix}\\ 
\end{pmatrix}$.

As $n \to +\propto$, we know that:

$cos\begin{pmatrix}\frac{\pi}{n}\\ \end{pmatrix}=1-\frac{\pi^2}{2n^2}+o\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{n^3}\\ \end{pmatrix}$. So, using Taylor expansion again:

$log\begin{pmatrix}
cos\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\pi}{n}\\ 
\end{pmatrix}\\ 
\end{pmatrix}=log\begin{pmatrix}1-\frac{\pi^2}{2n^2}+o\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{n^3}\\ \end{pmatrix} 
\end{pmatrix}=-\frac{\pi^2}{2n^2}+o\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{n^3}\\ \end{pmatrix}+o\begin{pmatrix}-\frac{\pi^2}{2n^2}+o\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{n^3}\\ \end{pmatrix} \\ \end{pmatrix}$
$=-\frac{\pi^2}{2n^2}+o\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{n^2}\\ \end{pmatrix}$

Thus we can finally calculate: $log(L)=\lim_{n\to+\propto}n\cdot log\begin{pmatrix}
cos\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\pi}{n}\\ 
\end{pmatrix}\\ 
\end{pmatrix}=\lim_{n\to+\propto}n\cdot \begin{pmatrix}
-\frac{\pi^2}{2n^2}+o\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{n^2}\\ \end{pmatrix}\\\end{pmatrix}=0$.

So $L=\lim_{n\to+\propto}\begin{pmatrix}
cos\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\pi}{n}\\ 
\end{pmatrix}\\ 
\end{pmatrix}^n=1$.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to calculate the limit of the original poster with neither series nor De L’Hospital’s rule, but only notable limits.

$\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{\log(\cos x)}{x^2}=$

$=-\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{\log\big[1+(\cos x-1)\big]}{(\cos x-1)}\cdot\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{1-\cos x}{x^2}=$

$=-1\cdot\dfrac12=-\dfrac12\;.$

By letting $\;x=\dfrac{\pi}n\;\big(n\in\mathbb{N}\land n\ge3\big)\;,\;$ it follows that

$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{n^2}{\pi^2}\log\left(\cos\dfrac{\pi}n\right)=-\dfrac12\;,$

$\begin{align}
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}n\log\left(\cos\dfrac{\pi}n\right)&=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{\pi^2}n\cdot\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{n^2}{\pi^2}\log\left(\cos\dfrac{\pi}n\right)=\\
&=0\cdot\left(-\dfrac12\right)=0\;.
\end{align}$

Consequently,

$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(\cos\dfrac{\pi}n\right)^n=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}e^{n\log\left(\cos\frac{\pi}n\right)}=e^0=1\;.$